# Class image not found when using intervention

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am using Laravel and Intervention to handle a file upload from the user, I have installed Intervention using Composer but when I try to use some of its functions I get this error message `Class 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image' not found` I have checked my app.php file and I have added the correct lines of code to aliases and providers but now I am not sure what is the problem

Here is my function

```
public function postAvatarUpload(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'image' => 'required|image|max:3000|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        ]);
        $user = Auth::user();

        $usersname = $user->username;
       $file = $request->file('image');
       // $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $ext= Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = $usersname . '.' . $ext;
        if (Storage::disk('public')->has($usersname)) {
            Storage::delete($usersname);
        }
           Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, File::get($file));

           $path = public_path('app/public/'. $filename);
            Auth::user()->update([
                'image' => $path,
            ]);
        $resizedImg = Image::make($path)->resize(200,200);
       // $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        return redirect()->route('profile.index', 
                ['username' => Auth::user()->username]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to import it at the top of the file, after the namespace. Since you say that you've set the facade up, all you need to do is:

```
use Image;
```

Comment: I was putting use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image; just tried what you said and I am getting Class 'Image' not found

Comment: This is a really stupid question, but it does have to be asked - are you sure that the package was actually installed, and that Composer didn't just update the composer.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Add facade and provider as described in the [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation). Then run `composer dumpauto -o` command.

Then add `use Image` to your class, or use it like this:

```
$resizedImg = \Image::make($path)->resize(200,200);
```

Comment: I have done this but still nothing the only thing that I can see from the documentation is that I do not have an image.php file in my config folder but I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: Try this command from documentation: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"` - this command should copy config file to `config` folder.

Comment: Thanks I have done this but I am getting Nothing to return for tag []